# Por que `bundle exec rake test` se queda colgado en Ubuntu 19.10 (PopOS)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby, test

Me integré a un equipo de desarrollo y tengo un proyecto en ruby (2.6.5) on rails (6) al cual estamos agregando pruebas para aumentar el coverage con simplecov. El problema es pasar del entorno de Mac CatalinaOS a Ubuntu.

Usamos el manejador de versiones `asdf` tenemos todas las dependencias instaladas localmente, la base de datos tambien, redis y sidekiq igual. El proyecto si puede ejecutarse; mas sin embargo, al querer correr las pruebas con `bundle exec rake test` Ubuntu se queda colgado tras correr algunas pruebas.

Algunos comentarios sugieren agregar el stacktrace que hace cuando queda el proceso colgado. No es muy util como ya lo mencione, pero aqui lo tienen.

```
bundle exec rake test
Run options: --seed 11427

# Running:

......^CInterrupted. Exiting...


Finished in 34.555812s, 0.1736 runs/s, 0.2894 assertions/s.
6 runs, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Coverage report generated for MiniTest to /home/code/coverage. 1160 / 9402 LOC (12.34%) covered.
Coverage (12.34%) is below the expected minimum coverage (95.00%).
SimpleCov failed with exit 2%
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/test_adapter.rb:50:in `enqueue_or_perform'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/test_adapter.rb:32:in `enqueue'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:53:in `block in enqueue'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `block in tag_logger'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `tag_logger'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/logging.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:49:in `enqueue'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:20:in `perform_later'
/home/alejandro/EXTRA/REPOS/cartera/test/jobs/expire_installments_job_test.rb:42:in `block in test_it_updates_credit_installments_state_to_more_than_one_expired'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activejob-5.2.4.1/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb:382:in `perform_enqueued_jobs'
/home/alejandro/EXTRA/REPOS/cartera/test/jobs/expire_installments_job_test.rb:41:in `test_it_updates_credit_installments_state_to_more_than_one_expired'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:98:in `block (3 levels) in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:195:in `capture_exceptions'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:270:in `time_it'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:94:in `block in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:365:in `on_signal'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:211:in `with_info_handler'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest/test.rb:93:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:1026:in `run_one_method'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:339:in `run_one_method'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:325:in `each'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:325:in `block in run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:365:in `on_signal'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:352:in `with_info_handler'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:324:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:10:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:164:in `block in __run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:164:in `map'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:164:in `__run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:141:in `run'
/home/alejandro/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/minitest-5.14.0/lib/minitest.rb:68:in `block in autorun'
```

Hemos probado, desinstalando las versiones de ruby, node y yarn. Reinstalando todo, e incluso reinstalando PopOS 19.10 y el problema persiste. Alguien sabe porque ruby queda colgado en Ubuntu bajo estas condiciones??

Comment: ¿puede que el problema sea de PopOS? ¿has probado a correr los tests en otro pc con Ubuntu? podría existir algún problema en el hardware. ¿has ejecutado `htop` para revisar el uso de cpu/mem mientras está corriendo los tests? quizás revisar los logs de sistema, `dmesg` o checa `/var/log` por algún indicio que te pueda dar respuesta. No se me ocurre mucho a decir verdad...

Comment: He corrido con htop y stacer, la máquina nunca llega ni al 50% de su capacidad. La maquina de ubuntu es usada para deep learning, asi que tiene muy buenos specs. dmesg y los logs no me sacaron de ningun apuro pues no hay un error solo queda colgado el proceso

Comment: No me queda claro, ¿queda colgado el proceso o la máquina? porque si es el proceso, podrías revisar `log/test` de tu proyecto rails a ver si da alguna pista.... que intentaría, quizás borrando todos los tests para ver si `rake test` al menos termina de ejecutarse. Si no pasa nada, entraría a probar en sacar del `Gemfile` las gemas que se encuentren en `group: :test`, quizás alguna esté compilada para usar librerías del sistema y esté dando problemas por alguna razón. Solo por tirar ideas.

Comment: Se cuelga el proceso, no la maquina. Y rake test lo deje correr por mas de 1 hora y no acabo asi que lo termine. En el group de test solo tengo simplecov, la quite y no hizo diferencia. Otra idea?

Comment: Ahhh es que como mencionaste `Ubuntu se queda colgado tras correr algunas pruebas` y que incluso formateaste, asumí que era la máquina la que te estaba dando problemas. Entonces, ¿te muestra algo el log de rails? si corres unas 3~4 veces el proceso y luego haces ctrl+c en cada uno ¿ves que los stacktrace sean similares para cada proceso? Como para dar alguna pista de donde se está quedando pegado. De hecho, agrega el stacktrace a la pregunta.

Comment: De todas formas, ¿no tienes más información que agregar? quizás parte del código o las gemas. Cuando ejecutas rake test ¿no te muestra nada en pantalla? ¿simplemente se queda en negro la pantalla?

Comment: Ya agregue el log que hace a la consola cuando se ejecuta el comando, queda colgado por mas de 20 min y en este caso como ven no corrio practicamente nada de las pruebas. Los log del sistema no tienen nada puesto que no hay un error, el tmp del proyecto tampoco. De ahi mi frustracion con este problema.

Comment: Prueba a instalar [`minitest-reporters`](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) y usar `Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new` como reporter para tener más info en pantalla de cual es el test que puede estar quedándose pegado. Y cuando hablo de log, me refiero al archivo de log, como te mencionaba en el 2do comentario, debería estar en `log/test.log`. Prueba en un terminal anexo `tail -f log/test.log` para que veas en vivo lo que está sucediendo por detrás y agrega la info que pueda ser relevante del log (o agrega un link a un pastebin si es mucha info para agregar a la pregunta).

Comment: Parece que está progresando a través las pruebas al menos un poquito, hay 10 assertions. Podrías probar `bundle exec rake test --verbose --trace=stdout` y ver que dice. Qué pasa si quitas todas las pruebas sino una?

Comment: Mostrare el `test.log` en cuanto pueda, por el momento estoy trabajando en la mac que si corre las pruebas debido al deadline. Y hare el `bundle exec rake test --verbose --trace=stdout` tambien para ver que es lo que hay de error aqui. Ayer lo ultimo que probaron en mi equipo fue usar Regolith live con todo el mismo setup y corre las pruebas sin problema. Algo me dice que es la distro, espero poder solucionarlo pues es imporante lo que tenemos de Machine Learning en ella.

Comment: listo, ahi tienen unas images de como corre lado a lado con el log, y el tail del log que para nosotros no ha sido util, si tienen alguna idea lo agradeceria mucho